# Running a Spring context test using programatic TestNG

Tags: java, spring, testng

I want to run my integration test programatically using the TestNG API

I figured that this can be done using

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
org.testng.TestNG testng = new org.testng.TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { SomeTest.class });
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
```

Now in the SomeTest class I have some spring resources autowired. I initialized the spring context but it seems that when TestNG runs the class it creates a new instance of the SomeTest.class by itself and not necessarily using Spring and then all the Autowiring that has happened thru the spring container and the @Autowired tag is lost. ( This is what my initial guess is and I may be wrong)

Is there a way that I can run the tests so that TestNG obtains the instance thru the Spring context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a test dependency on `SpringTest` and use one of the solutions from their [testing documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html).

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-test-config.xml" })
public class SomeSpringTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you need transactional support you can use `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`. Here is a relevant snippet from their documentation about accessing the `applicationContext` in `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` :

> AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests is an abstract base test class that
>   integrates the Spring TestContext Framework with explicit
>   ApplicationContext testing support in a TestNG environment. When you
>   extend AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests, you can access a protected
>   applicationContext instance variable that can be used to perform
>   explicit bean lookups or to test the state of the context as a whole.